# Disabling the top UIView from forwarding events to the views below it..

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableview and there is a occasion where I need to show a view which takes up the whole screen. This view is semi transparent so that you can see the tablewview under it.. I want to setup the view such that the swipes on the view do not go to the tableview. I have setup the view with the

```
    view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

However if I swipe it goes to the table view.. how can I have this top view trap all gestures and cancel them? Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to instantiate a new `UIWindow` (which you would then add your `UIView` to), your gestures and touches would then be recorded by this new window.  You could then create a new viewController class to handle any events you require.

When you wish to dismiss your `UIView` you'll want to also dismiss this new `UIWindow`.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: That would work, but this would mean that I need to know what view is under the main view.. Since I have different screens I won't know what is under the view mostly.. hence looking for a way to stop it from going under the view.

Comment: I edited my response to a new one, perhaps it will be of help?